# How to wrap sibling elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

The following markup will have some extra elements injected into it (i.e.: a `div` containing some flash for example).

How can I dynamically wrap all of the `p` tags in one `div` and add a button above it to toggle that newly made `div`?

```html
<div class="post">
  <p>blquehrgéoqihrteoijth</p>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <p>blquehrgéoqihrteoijth</p>
  <p>blquehrgéoqihrteoijth</p>
  <p>blquehrgéoqihrteoijth</p>
  <p>blquehrgéoqihrteoijth</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following for simplicity:

```
$('.post').prepend("<h3 class='showText'>biography</h3>\n<div class='toggle'>");
$('.post').append("</div>");
```

Should do what you require.

**Edit 1:** Added cballou's comment code here for easier readability:

```
$j('h3').live('click', function() {
  $j(this).toggleClass('hideText').slideToggle(300);
});
```

Comment: I concur with Topher.  You would also want to utilize the jQuery "live" function to allow for the slideToggle event like so:

$j('h3').live('click', function() { $j(this).toggleClass('hideText').slideToggle(300); });

Comment: Its obvioulsly a much more simple solution. But the markup itself will be injected by loads of other divs at times and I only want the toggle the p tags. Unfortunately I have no access server-side to change the markup there ...

Answer (score 1):

I'd just extract the existing HTML and wrap it (as text), then reinsert it.

```
$('.post').each( function() {
    $(this).html('<h3 class="showText">biogrpahy</h3><div class="toggle">'
                  + $(this).html()
                  + '</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$j('.post').wrapAll("<div class='toggle'></div>");
$j('.toggle').before('<h3 class="showText">bibliography</h3>');
$j('h3').live('click',function(){
    $j(this).toggleClass('hideText');
    $j('.toggle').slideToggle(300);
});
```